For SSO login Azure is used in Angular secret key is not saved any where in Front End and backend(PHP)
We have used Azure for sso login in angular project.
With keeping a auth config Json we execute it simply.
{
 issuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/v2.0',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin,
  clientId: `${environment.clientId}`,
 responseType: 'code',
  strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
  scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
}

when click on sso button a  redirct to microsoft link mentioned here and returns a token.It will send to backend in userinfo end point api the sends user data as response thus able to login
This is the basic step we are doing here.So it a secure methode without keepoing secret key any where in project we are using azure.
We want to add cretificate  based authentication for azure what all  steps we have to do for it in both front end and backend
Gone through microsoft documentation  given below @https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-angular-spa-app    but not find what to do  for cerificate based authentication on code side of  Angular and Php .what we actually doing is click on sso login token API call goes to microsoft and in response we get access token and refresh token as we said in this documentation   and call userinfo get API  to backend with this access token in request header authorization part. So I didn;t get an idea where we do certificate based authentication between this steps.

Have you tried any code on your end? If yes, please share it.

updated  in question please check

Are you trying with both frontend and backend?

Provided link is about Angular, if possible, share your git repo?

What is your Angular version?

angular 17.Frorend angular and backend php

So your using Azure B2C for Authentication.

I will try that and let you know.
